# SelectableEntityFilteringFeature with ArrayList Response: Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'com.Profile'

Tags: java, arraylist, jackson, dropwizard

**Dropwizard Application**

```
 environment.jersey().getResourceConfig()
                   .packages("com.resources")
                   .property(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.QUERY_PARAM_NAME,"fields")
                   .register(SelectableEntityFilteringFeature.class)
                   .register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

**Method in ProfileResource**

```
@GET
    @Path("/test/entity")
    @ApiOperation(value = "get profile", responseContainer = "List")
    @Timed
    @UnitOfWork
    public Response tesProfile(@QueryParam("profileId") List<String> profilesToInclude,
                                @QueryParam("fields") String fieldsToInclude) {
               Profile p = Profile.builder().firstName("x").lastName("y").build();
        Profile p1 = Profile.builder().firstName("a").lastName("b").build();
        Profile p2 = Profile.builder().firstName("c").lastName("d").build();
        List<Profile> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
        profiles.add(p);
        profiles.add(p1);
        profiles.add(p2);
        return Response.ok(profiles).build();
    }
```

**Error**

Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'com.Profile'; no FilterProvider configured (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

**Response**

400 Bad Request

The same code works fine if i try to return a single profile in Response instead of list of profiles

Comment: There are heaps of bug reports with this one and you might be better off writing it yourself. What it essentially does is to use jackson to filter the entitie's properties. You can achieve that by implementing your own  `ContextResolver` to hand the right ObjectMapper to your jackson filter and in there register a `FilterProvider` that returns a `SimpleBeanPropertyFilter` for your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`javax.ws.rs.core.Response` accepts `new GenericEntity<List<Profile>>(profileList){}`. 
So I would need to convert the list to GenericEntity and then back to response. It worked.

Comment: This worked for me too, but seems needlessly tedious to do for each resource that returns a Collection.